# Kubernetes CronJob startup prob

Tags: kubernetes

I'm starting with Kubernetes and I implemented a CronJob that runs a Java jar.
It works fine but what I have observed is that if for some reason (for example, a wrong secret key) the container does not start, the pod will sit there indefinitely with error status : CreateContainerConfigError.

Is there a way to automatically kill the pod when such situation occurs ?

I tried with startup probe as indicated in code below but the probe did not even run.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: appName
  namespace: appNamespace
  labels:
    app: appName
    release: production
    tiers: backend
spec:
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      backoffLimit: 2
      template:
        spec:
          volumes:
            - name: tmp-pod
              emptyDir: {}
          containers:
            - name: appName
              image: docker-image
              command: ["/bin/bash", "-c"]
              args:
                - |
                  touch /tmp/pod/app-started; 
                    java -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=75.0 -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom -jar /app.jar;
              volumeMounts:
                - mountPath: /tmp/pod
                  name: tmp-pod
              env:
                - name: env_var
                  value: value
              # if app is not started within 5m (30 * 10 = 300s), container will be killed.
              startupProbe:
                exec:
                  command:
                  - cat
                  - /tmp/pod/app-started
                initialDelaySeconds: 5
                periodSeconds: 10
                failureThreshold: 30
              resources:
                requests:
                  memory: "2200Mi"
                  cpu: "750m"
                limits:
                  memory: "2200Mi"
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
  schedule: "0 12 * * *"
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
```

Does CronJob not support probes ?
Or I'm doing something wrong ?

Would there be another way of killing container that is not able to start after some time ?

Comment: Unfortunately Cron jobs don't delete the pods in the Error state. It will always deploy the new pod until the job succeeds. You can try [TTLconnectors](https://people.wikimedia.org/~jayme/k8s-docs/v1.16/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/ttlafterfinished/#ttl-controller) which will clean up the job and its resources as soon as job done.
When you say to kill the container does that mean you want to delete the pods which are created by the job while the job is still running?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, kubernetes v1.23.14
It seems that the kubernetes has a bug with cronjobs probs

Events:

```
  Normal   Started                 3m38s  kubelet                  Started container k8s-costs
  Warning  Unhealthy               3m38s  kubelet                  Startup probe failed: cat: /var/run/secrets/vault-envs: No such file or directory
  Normal   Killing                 3m37s  kubelet                  Stopping container k8s-costs
```

kubelet said "Stopping container" but it still working

So as result I see that pod is Successed and everything fine, no alerts.
But really job execution was failed and already we in a fire